# Dropdown selected value defaults for first option

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Crazy stumped here. I have the attached dropdown form on my page. On change event I submit this form and capture the value in my Spring Controller. The issue is that the captured value is always coming up as 1. What am I missing here?

```
<form name="queuePositionForm" id="queuePositionForm" action="/updatePosition" method="post">
    <select name="selPosition" onChange="updatePosition()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

**updatePosition**

```
function updatePosition(){
    $('form#queuePositionForm').submit();
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePosition", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCarQueuePosition(@RequestParam(value = "selPosition", required = false) String position) throws IOException {
    //do something with position here.
    return "redirect:/confirmation";
}
```

Comment: I have this and it prints the value fine var sel = $('#selPosition:selected').text();
          alert('sel ' + sel);

Comment: How are you capturing the value in controller ? I know it's in request param. But what are you doing with it. Can you share that code?

Comment: @Amit.rk3 I think I found the issue. There are multiple dropdown forms being created dynamically on my page with a for loop. It's always capturing the value of first form on the page. Now the issue is, how do I make this work for all the forms on my page? this.form.submit() won't help me I think

Comment: If your page has multiple forms with same id, you might want to change them by assigning a counter to them. Like `id="queuePositionForm_${i}"` where `i` would be loop counter. Also assign `id` to select like `select name="selPosition" id="selPosition_${i}"`. This way you can get the id of current `select` on its `onChange` and get the form index by doing `index=id.split("_")[1]`. And then `$("form#queuePositionForm"+index).submit()` . I can post it as proper answer if you are have access to change html

Comment: Thanks @Amit.rk3. I think this should get me going. If you can post a pseudo code answer, I can pick that as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `JSP` has multiple forms with same `id` and `name`, it would be better if you change it and have unique ids assigned to each of them by assigning a counter suffix to id. Also assign id to each select element as shown below. Here `i` will be counter for loop which generates these forms.

```
<form name="queuePositionForm" id="queuePositionForm_${i}" action="/updatePosition" method="post">
    <select name="selPosition" id="selPosition_${i}" onChange="updatePosition(${i})">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

With this you can have your updatePosition function as below which will submit correct enclosing form.

```
function updatePosition(formIndex){
   $('form#queuePositionForm_'+formIndex).submit();
}
```

Comment: this thing is throwing: TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Comment: @user1195192 updated answer, just pass the index to function itself

Comment: Just tried. It's still giving 1 in the controller. I am going crazy here lol

Comment: this is so weird, I just changed the onChange event to this.form.submit() and everything started working fine.